# Simplify $1 - \cos x + \sin x - \tan x$.

Tags: trigonometry

I somehow can't find a way to do this, the expression already seems simplified to me. I've tried factoring, I got $$(\cos x - \sin x)(1 - \cos x) \over \cos x$$ but obviously that's not simplified and I can't see how I could continue.

Comment: Maybe  $(1-\tan x)(1-\cos x)$ is the desired simplification? (Not that it's really simpler, but, who knows?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not far off. If you distribute the $\cos x$ into the first factor on the numerator you get
$$1-\cos x+\sin x-\tan x = (1-\tan x)(1-\cos x)$$
I think this is about as 'simplified' as you can expect it to be.

Comment: +1 In the olden days before calculators, two trig calculations would be better than three. And also, any division is something to avoid.